# How do I stop SublimeText 3 from changing the owner on files in cygwin64

Tags: file-permissions, sublime-text-3

Sublime Text 3 build 3047 is changing the owner of files that I edit to Administrator. This happens on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with cygwin64.

The causes a problem with the ~/.ssh/config file. When I try to clone a git repo with ssh using an alias in the ~/.ssh/config file it refuses to read it because the owner is incorrect.  Changing the owner back solves the problem, but I have to do this every time I edit a file.

Is there a setting that can prevent this or is it a bug?

Comment: You could be running Sublime as Administrator. Are you starting it from bash? If so, cygwin could be set to run as admin - see if you can change its settings.

Comment: I'm not running Sublime as Administrator.  I start it from the Task Bar and I don't use the options to run as Administrator.

Comment: are any other files you edit having their owner changed, or is it just your ssh config?

Comment: All files I edit have ownership changed to Administrator.

Comment: Having the cygwin64 owner changed to Administrator doesn't matter for most files, but with ssh related files it does matter.